# Proof that $SupA$ = $SupB$

Tags: calculus

Let $A,B\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be unempty and bounded from above.

Also: $\forall a\in A$ $ \hspace{2mm}\exists b \in B \hspace{2mm} a\leq b$

and $\forall b\in B$ $ \hspace{2mm}\exists a \in A \hspace{2mm} b\leq a$

I need to proove that $SupA$ = $SupB$.

It is kind of appernt to the eye, but im having a trouble proving that.

My intuition tells me that I need to prove that $A=B$ but I need to do it formally. I know that theyre both bounded and have their supremums.

I was thinking that maybe I should argue that $\exists\hspace{2mm} b_0\in B$ such that this $b_0\geq a \hspace{2mm}\forall a\in A$ and the same for

$a_0\geq b \hspace{2mm}\forall b\in B$

Comment: Do you mean "bounded from above"?

Comment: @Dave Yes! im so sorry!

Comment: Btw, you can use `\sup` to get $\sup$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $m_A$, $m_B$ be the suprema of $A$ and $B$, respectively.

Given $a\in A$, there exists $b\in B$ such that $b\ge a$ and since $m_B\ge b$ for all $b\in B$, $m_B\ge a$ for all $a\in A$. Therefore, $m_B$ is an upper bound for $A$ and since $m_A$ is the least upper bound, $m_B\ge m_A$.

The exact same argument can be used to show that $m_A\ge m_B$. Therefore, $m_A=m_B$.

Answer (score 0):

We know that $\sup(A)$ is an upper bound for $A$, i.e. $\forall a\in A,~a\leq\sup(A)$. Thus, for each $b\in B$, there exists $a\in A$ such that $b\leq a\leq\sup(A)$. Hence, $\sup(A)$ is an upper bound for $B$. Thus, by definition of supremum for $B$, we have $\sup(A)\geq \sup(B)$. Apply the argument symmetrically for $B$ and compare the inequalities at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The two sets need not be equal. 
In fact they can be disjoint.
Ex:
A=] 0;1[ inter Q
B=]0;1[ inter I
I:=irrational numbers
inter:=intersection

Comment: You're not wrong, but this would be better left as a comment since you're not really offering a full answer (i.e. addressing how the OP *should* solve it, then). Also, here's [a reference for MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you might find useful, which is preferred for writing up and rendering your math text on this site.